# What would this surface be topologically?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-topology

The construction may remind you of a torus, but it intersects itself in three dimensions. I thought it could be a Klein Bottle, but I'm not sure.

The surface is traced by $S(p,q)= 10(\hat{e}_x\sin(p) +\hat{e}_y\cos(p))+(\hat{e}_y \sin (q) + \hat{e}_z \cos(q))$
Basically we have one big circle of radius 10 going around on the x-y plane and one small circle of radius 1 going around each point of that circle, but fixed to the y-z plane instead of rotating around like in a torus.

Could anybody give me a hint? I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I tried to look at from above (my eye stare straight down to x-y plane) and based on your descriptions, i think it is something like torus after you removed two disks of opposite ends.

Comment: After having a bit more of a think for myself I'm back to saying it might be a torus if the two circles 'change role'. If the big one becomes the small one and vice versa I can deform the shape of the circles in a way that leaves me with a torus that has no intersections.